# Crystal Report Formula -running total 4Help

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I need to count the total # of orders that are Co-signed within a specific time range and count the orders which are not.

The problem is I have orderId and OrderFunction field with multiple value and I need to display if with that multiple value one of them satisfy as co-sgin then the orderid should display as signed order.
I have below formula to dispaly as signed order but I am also getting else display because of the multiple valu associate with the same orderId.
Formula:
if {Command.ChangedDateTime}<{@Creation+48}AND {Command.OrderFunction}="Co-Sign Order"
then " signed" else "not signed"

```html
       
Order_oid  OrderFunction    Signed/NotSigned Orders
101       
       
      Co-Sign Order         signed orders 
       
      Acknowledge Order     not signed orders 
       
      Discontinue Order     not signed orders 
       
102       
       
    Acknowledge Order         not signed orders 
        
    Revise Order             not signed orders 
       
    Discontinue Order         not signed orders
```

so for above example when this order101 has signed orders, then i want running total of only signed or I want that order to be displayed as only signed order

Thank you for any help.